# Setting objects to other object methods?

Tags: object

Forgot what the technical term was for this,

bs is a BufferStrategy
gfx is a Graphics object

this is the line of focus:

```
gfx = bs.getDrawGraphics();
```

^ what is the technical term of this object being set to another objects method and explain the logic behind it.

Comment: I guess the words you are looking for are "Initializing" ,"Assigning" a variable.The process behind https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=450maTzSIvA

Comment: But gtx is a Graphics objects
    private static Graphics gtx;

Comment: Yes and bs.getDrawGraphics() returns a Graphic object which will be "assigned" to gfx variable without any "casting" involved. So this line is valid.I'm guessing you are concerned about the return type of the getDrawGraphics() or is it something else you are concerned?

Comment: Nope i understand the concept behind it now.